# What its mean by Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument in r

Tags: r, seq

Code below used to web scrape a website using API call. I just have to change the startDate and endDate to get data set that I want. Previously it works fine, doing its loops wonderfully but after I did some modification on the html_nodes() part - try to extract different section in the webpage, it keep return me data of the same date. with error warning 'Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument in r'. What should be done here?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
library(beepr)

get_sounding_data <- function(region = c("naconf", "samer", "pac", "nz", "ant",
                                     "np", "europe", "africa", "seasia", "mideast"),
                          date,
                          from_hr = c("00", "12", "all"),
                          to_hr = c("00", "12", "all"),
                          station_number = 48615) {

  # we use these pkgs (the readr and dplyr dependencies removed)
  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
    require("xml2", quietly = TRUE)
    require("httr", quietly = TRUE)
    require("rvest", quietly = TRUE)
  })

  # validate region
  region <- match.arg(
    arg = region,
    choices = c(
      "naconf", "samer", "pac", "nz", "ant",
      "np", "europe", "africa", "seasia", "mideast"
    )
  )

  # validates the date for us if it's a character string
  date <- as.Date(date)

  # get year and month
  year <- as.integer(format(date, "%Y"))
  stopifnot(year %in% 1973:as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")))

  year <- as.character(year)
  month <- format(date, "%m")

# we need these to translate day & *_hr to the param the app needs
c(
"0100", "0112", "0200", "0212", "0300", "0312", "0400", "0412",
"0500", "0512", "0600", "0612", "0700", "0712", "0800", "0812",
"0900", "0912", "1000", "1012", "1100", "1112", "1200", "1212",
"1300", "1312", "1400", "1412", "1500", "1512", "1600", "1612",
"1700", "1712", "1800", "1812", "1900", "1912", "2000", "2012",
"2100", "2112", "2200", "2212", "2300", "2312", "2400", "2412",
"2500", "2512", "2600", "2612", "2700", "2712", "2800", "2812",
"2900", "2912", "3000", "3012", "3100", "3112"
  ) -> hr_vals

c(
"01/00Z", "01/12Z", "02/00Z", "02/12Z", "03/00Z", "03/12Z", "04/00Z",
"04/12Z", "05/00Z", "05/12Z", "06/00Z", "06/12Z", "07/00Z", "07/12Z",
"08/00Z", "08/12Z", "09/00Z", "09/12Z", "10/00Z", "10/12Z", "11/00Z",
"11/12Z", "12/00Z", "12/12Z", "13/00Z", "13/12Z", "14/00Z", "14/12Z",
"15/00Z", "15/12Z", "16/00Z", "16/12Z", "17/00Z", "17/12Z", "18/00Z",
"18/12Z", "19/00Z", "19/12Z", "20/00Z", "20/12Z", "21/00Z", "21/12Z",
"22/00Z", "22/12Z", "23/00Z", "23/12Z", "24/00Z", "24/12Z", "25/00Z",
"25/12Z", "26/00Z", "26/12Z", "27/00Z", "27/12Z", "28/00Z", "28/12Z",
"29/00Z", "29/12Z", "30/00Z", "30/12Z", "31/00Z", "31/12Z"
  ) -> hr_inputs

  hr_trans <- stats::setNames(hr_vals, hr_inputs)

  o_from_hr <- from_hr <- as.character(tolower(from_hr))
  o_to_hr <- to_hr <- as.character(tolower(to_hr))

  if ((from_hr == "all") || (to_hr == "all")) {
  from_hr <- to_hr <- "all"
  } else {

  from_hr <- hr_trans[sprintf("%s/%02dZ", format(date, "%d"), as.integer(from_hr))]
match.arg(from_hr, hr_vals)

 to_hr <- hr_trans[sprintf("%s/%02dZ", format(date, "%d"), as.integer(to_hr))]
match.arg(to_hr, hr_vals)
 }

  # clean up the station number if it was entered as a double
  station_number <- as.character(as.integer(station_number))

# execute the API call
httr::GET(
url = "http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding",
query = list(
  region = region,
  TYPE = "TEXT:LIST",
  YEAR = year,
  MONTH = sprintf("%02d", as.integer(month)),
  FROM = from_hr,
  TO = to_hr,
  STNM = station_number
   )
  ) -> res

  # check for super bad errors (that we can't handle nicely)
  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  # get the page content
  doc <- httr::content(res, as="text")

  # if the site reports no data, issue a warning and return an empty data frame
  if (grepl("Can't get", doc)) {
    doc <- xml2::read_html(doc)
    msg <- rvest::html_nodes(doc, "body")
    msg <- rvest::html_text(msg, trim=TRUE)
    msg <- gsub("\n\n+.*$", "", msg)
    warning(msg)
    return(data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
   }

  # if the site reports no data, issue a warning and return an empty data frame
  if (grepl("Can't get", doc)) {
    doc <- xml2::read_html(doc)
    msg <- rvest::html_nodes(doc, "body")
    msg <- rvest::html_text(msg, trim=TRUE)
    msg <- gsub("\n\n+.*$", "", msg)
    warning(msg)
    return(data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
   }

  # turn it into something we can parse
  doc <- xml2::read_html(doc)

  raw_dat <- doc %>%
    html_nodes("h3+ pre") %>% 
    html_text()

  indices <- raw_dat %>% 
    str_split(pattern = "\n", simplify = T) %>% 
    map_chr(str_squish) %>% 
    tibble(x = .) %>% 
    separate(x, into = c("Station", "Value"), sep = ": ") %>% 
    filter(!is.na(Value))

  data <- tidyr::spread(indices, Station, Value)
  data
    }

startDate <- as.Date("01-11-1979", format="%d-%m-%y")
endDate <- as.Date("31-01-1980",format="%d-%m-%y")

days <- seq(startDate, endDate, "1 day")

lapply(days[1:92], function(day) {
  get_sounding_data(
    region = "seasia",
    date = day,
    from_hr = "00",
    to_hr = "00",
    station_number = "48615"
  )
}) -> soundings_48615

warnings()

new_df <- map(soundings_48615, . %>% mutate_all(parse_guess))
dat <- bind_rows(new_df)
dat <- dat %>% separate(col =`Observation time`, into = c('Date', 'time'), sep = '/')

dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, format = "%y%m%d")

#save in text file
write.csv(dat, 'c:/Users/Hp/Documents/yr/climatology/yr_SoundingIndexLowerPart/1979.csv')

get_sounding_data <- NULL
beep()
```

Comment: Do you really need such a big code example to reproduce the error? You will have greater chances of getting an answer if the example is *minimal*.

Comment: I'm not sure where exactly goes wrong, just hoping no information left behind .. Thank you for yr concern

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the error you are having right now, is date format based. More specific the following times

```
as.Date("01-11-1979", format="%d-%m-%y")
as.Date("31-01-1980",format="%d-%m-%y")
```

outputs

```
"2019-11-01"
"2019-01-31"
```

R's date/time format is international standard `yyyy-mm-dd`. As such the `"2019-11-01"` comes after `"2019-01-31"` time wise. As such this will cause sequence to fail if it tries to iterate 1 positive day at a time. The formatting is the problem here, for this to be solved there is a very simple solution. Always work in international standard date formats, as these will be recognized by (almost) all programs.

As such change the date sequence part of your code to

```
....
startDate <- as.Date("1979-11-01")
endDate <- as.Date("1980-01-31")

days <- seq(startDate, endDate, "1 day")
....
```

Note the format change. As for why it changes 1979 to 2019, i am not entirely sure, someone else might have a more intricate answer for this weird behaviour.

Comment: Maybe not, the error is in `seq.int` not in `seq.Date`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, what is that means, which part do you think effect the `seq.int`? I haven't write `seq.int` in my code anyway...

Comment: @Oliver , the result however return 2014 data, which is the first data acquired during modification.. I wonder where this data being stored because when I checking data in the environment, they were all dated on 2019..

Comment: The full address was look like this (http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding?region=seasia&TYPE=TEXT%3ALIST&YEAR=2019&MONTH=01&FROM=0100&TO=3112&STNM=48615)  I wonder if the date structure affected inside API call

Comment: @RuiBarradas : `seq` defaults to calling `seq.default` or the specific class of your input. As the input is of class `Date` it will call `seq.Date`. Looking into the code of `seq.Date` one may note that calls `seq.int` after performing a couple of checks.

Comment: @SitiSal. I am not certain what you mean by your error? 
Please edit your post to illustrate what your error is (extend the current post) explaining what you are seeing, and what you are currently getting. Providing illustrative example of the expected and what you are getting is going to improve the chance for a fullfilling answer.

Comment: @Oliver, I'm making a new question after some more trial. You may check it here if you interested. Thanks! (https://stackoverflow.com/q/54723136/7356308)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I was trying to create a sequence of dates using the seq() function. Turns out I was putting the start and end dates in the wrong order.

This would give me the error:

```
seq(as.Date("2012-12-30"), as.Date("2011-01-04"), by="days")
```

Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

But this would not give me the error and would give me my date sequence:

```
seq(as.Date("2011-12-30"), as.Date("2012-01-04"), by="days")
```