# Web scrape request does not work for long date range input in R

Tags: html, r

The code here works for web scraping by sending repeated request based on the input date range (`startDate` and `endDate`). Then data will be saved in csv file. I have used this code before for different xPath @ `html_node()` argument, and it works fine. Now with different xPath, seems like it cannot works for longer date range. With this one, I also can't detect which data went missing because the code fails to work when the heading element applied as `attr()`. I've tried increase the range slowly and it only works until [1:29]. After that, no matter what the range used, it keep showing the old return. In some cases, I can see `str(new_df)` complete the request, but it keep saving the old return, as if the `bind_rows` fail. Sometimes (by using date of different year), I was able to extract the range desired by slowly increase the range (desired range is [1:92]). It makes me excited, but when I change the date input to get other different year it return the last record. sometimes with error, and sometimes the error not appear. I include the lengthy code here so anyone can reproduce it. I wonder if the website burdened by repeated request or my pc getting muzzy. Kindly help.

```
get_sounding_data <- function(region = c("naconf", "samer", "pac", "nz", "ant",
                                     "np", "europe", "africa", "seasia", "mideast"),
                          date,
                          from_hr = c("00", "12", "all"),
                          to_hr = c("00", "12", "all"),
                          station_number = 48615) {

  # we use these pkgs (I removed the readr and dplyr dependencies)
  suppressPackageStartupMessages({
require("xml2", quietly = TRUE)
require("httr", quietly = TRUE)
require("rvest", quietly = TRUE)
  })

  # validate region
  region <- match.arg(
arg = region,
choices = c(
  "naconf", "samer", "pac", "nz", "ant",
  "np", "europe", "africa", "seasia", "mideast"
    )
  )

  # this actually validates the date for us if it's a character string
  date <- as.Date(date)

  # get year and month
  year <- as.integer(format(date, "%Y"))
  stopifnot(year %in% 1973:as.integer(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y")))

  year <- as.character(year)
  month <- format(date, "%m")

  # we need these to translate day & *_hr to the param the app needs
  c(
"0100", "0112", "0200", "0212", "0300", "0312", "0400", "0412",
"0500", "0512", "0600", "0612", "0700", "0712", "0800", "0812",
"0900", "0912", "1000", "1012", "1100", "1112", "1200", "1212",
"1300", "1312", "1400", "1412", "1500", "1512", "1600", "1612",
"1700", "1712", "1800", "1812", "1900", "1912", "2000", "2012",
"2100", "2112", "2200", "2212", "2300", "2312", "2400", "2412",
"2500", "2512", "2600", "2612", "2700", "2712", "2800", "2812",
"2900", "2912", "3000", "3012", "3100", "3112"
  ) -> hr_vals

  c(
"01/00Z", "01/12Z", "02/00Z", "02/12Z", "03/00Z", "03/12Z", "04/00Z",
"04/12Z", "05/00Z", "05/12Z", "06/00Z", "06/12Z", "07/00Z", "07/12Z",
"08/00Z", "08/12Z", "09/00Z", "09/12Z", "10/00Z", "10/12Z", "11/00Z",
"11/12Z", "12/00Z", "12/12Z", "13/00Z", "13/12Z", "14/00Z", "14/12Z",
"15/00Z", "15/12Z", "16/00Z", "16/12Z", "17/00Z", "17/12Z", "18/00Z",
"18/12Z", "19/00Z", "19/12Z", "20/00Z", "20/12Z", "21/00Z", "21/12Z",
"22/00Z", "22/12Z", "23/00Z", "23/12Z", "24/00Z", "24/12Z", "25/00Z",
"25/12Z", "26/00Z", "26/12Z", "27/00Z", "27/12Z", "28/00Z", "28/12Z",
"29/00Z", "29/12Z", "30/00Z", "30/12Z", "31/00Z", "31/12Z"
  ) -> hr_inputs

  hr_trans <- stats::setNames(hr_vals, hr_inputs)

  o_from_hr <- from_hr <- as.character(tolower(from_hr))
  o_to_hr <- to_hr <- as.character(tolower(to_hr))

  if ((from_hr == "all") || (to_hr == "all")) {
from_hr <- to_hr <- "all"
  } else {

from_hr <- hr_trans[sprintf("%s/%02dZ", format(date, "%d"), as.integer(from_hr))]
match.arg(from_hr, hr_vals)

to_hr <- hr_trans[sprintf("%s/%02dZ", format(date, "%d"), as.integer(to_hr))]
match.arg(to_hr, hr_vals)

  }

  # clean up the station number if it was entered as a double
  station_number <- as.character(as.integer(station_number))

  # execute the API call
  httr::GET(
url = "http://weather.uwyo.edu/cgi-bin/sounding",
query = list(
  region = region,
  TYPE = "TEXT:LIST",
  YEAR = year,
  MONTH = sprintf("%02d", as.integer(month)),
  FROM = from_hr,
  TO = to_hr,
  STNM = station_number
    )
  ) -> res

  # check for super bad errors (that we can't handle nicely)
  httr::stop_for_status(res)

  # get the page content
  doc <- httr::content(res, as="text")

  # if the site reports no data, issue a warning and return an empty data frame
  if (grepl("Can't get", doc)) {
 doc <- xml2::read_html(doc)
 msg <- rvest::html_nodes(doc, "body")
 msg <- rvest::html_text(msg, trim=TRUE)
 msg <- gsub("\n\n+.*$", "", msg)
 warning(msg)
 return(data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
  }

  # turn it into something we can parse
  doc <- xml2::read_html(doc)

  # get the metadata
  #meta <- rvest::html_node(doc, "h2")
  #meta <- rvest::html_text(meta, trim=TRUE)
  #attr(doc, "meta") <- meta

  raw_dat <- doc %>%
   html_nodes("pre + h3") %>% 
   html_text()

  indices <- doc %>% 
    str_split(pattern = "\n", simplify = T) %>% 
    map_chr(str_squish) %>% 
    tibble(x = .) %>% 
    separate(x, into = c("Station", "Value"), sep = ": ") %>% 
    filter(!is.na(Value))

  data <- tidyr::spread(indices, Station, Value)
  data

}

startDate <- as.Date("01-11-1984", format="%d-%m-%Y")
endDate <- as.Date("04-11-1984",format="%d-%m-%Y")
#startDate <- as.Date("01-11-1984", format="%d-%m-%Y")
#endDate <- as.Date("31-01-1985",format="%d-%m-%Y")

days <- seq(startDate, endDate, "day")

#wanted to have [1:92], but its not working
lapply(days[1:4], function(day) {
  get_sounding_data(
    region = "seasia",
    date = day,
    from_hr = "00",
    to_hr = "00",
    station_number = "48615"
  )
}) -> soundings_48615

warnings()  
new_df <- map(soundings_48615, . %>% mutate_all(parse_guess))
#str(new_df)

library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
dat <- bind_rows(new_df)
dat <- dat %>% separate(col =`Observation time`, into = c('Date', 'time'), sep = '/')

dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date, format = "%y%m%d")

#save in text file
library(xlsx)
write.csv(dat, 'c:/Users/Hp/Documents/1984.csv')
get_sounding_data <- NULL
```

error

```
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
 Column `1000 hPa to 500 hPa thickness` can't be converted from numeric to character
dat <- dat %>% separate(col =`Observation time`, into = c('Date', 'time'), sep = '/')
 Error in eval_tidy(enquo(var), var_env) : 
  object 'Observation time' not found
```

I've install different R version, but this error keep come out. So I ignore it.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: fun(libname, pkgname)
error: No CurrentVersion entry in Software/JavaSoft registry! Try re- 
installing Java and make sure R and Java have matching architectures.
```

Comment: This "Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) " looks like the page request is returning a different set of columns than what is prior pages were returning.  Have you verified that the data is consistent over the entire time frame of interest?  For the second error, I would recommend the `readxl` library instead of `xlsx` in order to avoid the Java dependence.

Comment: @Dave2e, there is possibility to have missing data from each page, however the column number should maintain because the 1st column is actually the parameter and 2nd column contains respected value. Unless the function pointing out at different table in the page..

Comment: Looking at your request, is it possible you are requesting data which does not exist?  There is no November 31st, thus the return, thus maybe the NULL return is causing the error?

Comment: I think that happen because I already filter some of the NA value, thus some variables also missing from the lists.